# Graphs using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have troubles trying to use ggplot2 package. All the graphs I got are empty

```
ggplot(data=dataa,aes(x=Description, y=RPKM,fill=Condition)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

`dataa` is a piece of a bigger data frame like this:

```
Description Tissue  Condition   RPKM
re           brain  obese       34
re1          brain  Fit         23
re2          brain  Slim        67
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

real data i have :

```
Description Tissue  Condition   RPKM 
peptidase Brain Obese   0.5
protein Brain   Obese   1.4 
Glucagon    Brain   Fit 0.06 
kinase  Brain   Fit 0.9 
transporter Brain   Obese   4.8 
Secretogran Brain   Slim    87.2
```

Script:

```
tissues<-factor(unique(RPKMl123upslim$Tissue)) 
for (n in 1:6) { 
    i=c(0,108,216,324,432,540) 
    #datos<-data.frame(RPKMl123upslim[(i[n]+1):(i[n]+108),]) 
    View(datos) 
    ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=Description, y=Expression,fill=Condition)) + 
        geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity", colour="black",las=2) 

    path100<-file.path("pajarito",paste("Lupslimrpkm_",tissues[n],".jpg", sep=" ")) 
    jpeg(file=path100) 
    dev.off() 
}
```

–  Roberto Carlos 2 days ago

Comment: Is it just your files are empty? Because you `jpeg()` starts a file and `dev.off()` closes the file. With no lines of code in between, you're not putting anything in the file. If you `print()` your ggplot between those lines it should work. Or get rid of `jpeg()` and `dev.off()` and use `ggsave()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
dataa <- data.frame(Description =c("re","re1","re2")
          ,Condition=c("Obese","Fit","Slim"),RPKM=c(34,23,67))

ggplot(data=dataa,aes(x=Description, y=RPKM,fill=Condition))+ 
         geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")`
```

This is what i get

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks  user2673238; but the point is Im using a data frame, imported from a text file and I dont know why my graphs are totally empty still.

Comment: hmm can you give some example data?. or perhaps figure out which what types of data you got?.  `typeof(dataa$RPKM)` for example.

Comment: Description Tissue Condition RPKM
peptidase  Brain Obese 0.5
protein Brain Obese 1.4
Glucagon Brain Fit 0.06
kinase Brain Fit 0.9
transporter Brain Obese 4.8
Secretogran Brain Slim 87.2

Script:  tissues<-factor(unique(RPKMl123upslim$Tissue))
for (n in 1:6) 
{ i=c(0,108,216,324,432,540)
#datos<-data.frame(RPKMl123upslim[(i[n]+1):(i[n]+108),])
View(datos)
ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=Description, y=Expression,fill=Condition))+ geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity", colour="black",las=2)
path100<-file.path("pajarito",paste("Lupslimrpkm_",tissues[n],".jpg", sep=" "))
jpeg(file=path100)
dev.off()
}

Comment: Can you include some sample data that isolates and shows the problem you are having?

Comment: sure I have added in the original question thanks  user2673238

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help, now I want to share the code that worked:

```
 dev.set(dev.prev()) 
#dev.new(width=10, height=12)
 path100<-file.path("D:","final.results",paste("skin005",".png", sep=" "))
 png(file=path100, width=1000, height=10000, res=100)
plot(1:100)
attach(skin005RPKMS) #previous data frame with all information
q<-skin005RPKMS[(Skin.Obese > Skin.Fit) & (Skin.Obese > Skin.Slim),]
colnames(q)<-c("Description","Skin.Slim","Skin.Fit","Skin.Obese")
q1<-melt(q,id.vars="Description") #variable contain the different condition    of the experiment and value the data.
p <- ggplot(q1, aes(y=Description,x=variable))+ geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) +   scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("white","azure2","yellow","blue","orchid","orange red","red","black"), values=rescale(c(0,1,10,50,100,500,1000,4500)),  guide="colorbar") + xlab("Condition") + ylab("Genes")
print(p)
dev.off()
```